# Is the process $\pi^0 \to \gamma\gamma\gamma$ kinematically possible?

Tags: particle-physics, photons, conservation-laws, standard-model, pions

The process$$
\pi^0 \to \gamma\gamma\gamma
$$is forbidden because of charge conjugation violation, but I was wondering whether, regardless of charge conjugation violation, this process could be kinematically possible or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is kinematically possible. A few particles in the standard model decay with the same kinematics, like the $\rm J/\psi$, which decays as $\rm J/\psi\to3\gamma$, with a branching ratio of $1.16\pm.22\times10^{-5}$, [according to the Particle Data Group](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/tables/rpp2015-tab-mesons-c-cbar.pdf).

More generally, any decay $\rm X\to n\gamma$, with $n>1$, is *always* possible. More photons makes it easier to conserve energy and momentum, not harder. Of course, it may be forbidden for other reasons (like $\rm J/\psi\to\gamma\gamma$ is forbidden by C symmetry).